# get respond after submit with jQuery and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have an event that submits automatically,

i already put `url` and `method: POST` on `<form>` tag, so i just called `$('#myform').submit()`

and after that submit, it will redirect to another page for that respond,

what I asked here, i want to do something after it submitted successfully, I was using `setTimeout` but we don't know when the page redirect, right? it because of the internet connection as well, so how do u handle this ??

Comment: what do you mean by after submitting? after the page redirect?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#myform').submit()` will auto submit the form.

What you need to do is :-

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    // DO STUFF HERE...
    return true; // return false to cancel form submission
});
```

Now perform the action and return `true`.

Comment: what is the return true for? because? , i want to uncheck radio button after it redirects successfully, i tried using steTimeOut, but it was too quick to uncheck because the page still on that page, and not redirect right

Comment: `return true` submits the form, once all modifications are done.

Comment: it doesnt wait the sumitted finish, i want to wait the submmited finish and do something